# Create A Drop Down Filter Using PHP, Javascript and JSON

Tags: php, javascript, json, drop-down-menu, filtering

What I want to do is create a drop-down menu where when you select an item, the page instantly refreshes to show only the filtered elements that the user selects.

Here is the base HTML:

```
<SELECT>
 <OPTION selected>Show All</OPTION>
 <OPTION>Color</OPTION>
 <OPTION>Shape</OPTION></SELECT>
```

Notice "Show All" has the selected parameter. This will be the default selection.

Suppose I have a list of colors and shapes below, and they are all stored into a JSON table. Both will share the same variable called $type:

Orange, Hexagon, Red, Square, Yellow, Blue, Triangle, Circle, Green, Pentagon, Violet

JSON Table:

```
{"table":[
  {"name":"orange", "type":"color"},
  {"name":"hexagon", "type":"shape"},
  {"name":"red", "type":"color"},
  {"name":"square", "type":"shape"},
  {"name":"yellow", "type":"color"},
  {"name":"blue", "type":"color"},
  {"name":"triangle", "type":"shape"},
  {"name":"circle", "type":"shape"},
  {"name":"green", "type":"color"},
  {"name":"pentagon", "type":"shape"},
  {"name":"violet", "type":"color"}
]}
```

PHP will collect the information that will be used for the filter:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($json["table"]); $i++) {
 $name = $json["table"][$i]["name"];
 $type = $json["table"][$i]["type"];
 if ($type == "color") {
  // Refresh to show only words of color upon selecting Color from the menu
 }
 else if ($type == "shape") {
  // Refresh to show only words of shape upon selecting Shape from the menu
 }
 else {
  // Refresh to show everything by default or when selecting Show All from the menu
 }
}
```

How do I create this drop-down menu so that it does the specified actions? I know for sure Javascript is involved because this person posted a demo which demonstrates exactly what I want - http://jsfiddle.net/trewknowledge/jJZEN/ - but I don't know how to pull this off.

Comment: Your looking for someone to write all this code for you or do you just want a hint on what the JavaScript needs to look like?

Comment: I have the SELECTED, table, and PHP portions up. So, half-and-half. Get me started, and then give me a hint on what you believe are the easy parts. Be warned: I have very little experience with Javascript. PHP, I'm okay with, even if I'm seldom new to the language.

Answer (score 0):

Well, let me start by saying I think you'd be much better off parsing the JSON in your JavaScript.....

```
$(function () {
    var tblData = {
        "table": [{
            "name": "orange",
                "type": "color"
        }, {
            "name": "hexagon",
                "type": "shape"
        }, {
            "name": "red",
                "type": "color"
        }, {
            "name": "square",
                "type": "shape"
        }, {
            "name": "yellow",
                "type": "color"
        }, {
            "name": "blue",
                "type": "color"
        }, {
            "name": "triangle",
                "type": "shape"
        }, {
            "name": "circle",
                "type": "shape"
        }, {
            "name": "green",
                "type": "color"
        }, {
            "name": "pentagon",
                "type": "shape"
        }, {
            "name": "violet",
                "type": "color"
        }]
    };

    var objData = $.parseJSON(tblData);
    $.each(objData, function (i, v) {
        if (v[i].type == 'color') {
            $('#colors').append(v[i].name);
        } else {
            $('#shapes').append(v[i].name);
        }
    });
    $(document).on('change','#selType', function() {
        $('.twoDIVS').hide();
        var strType = $('option:selected',this).val();
        $('#' + strType).show();
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<SELECT id="selType">
    <OPTION value="all" selected="selected">Show All</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="color">Color</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="shape">Shape</OPTION>
</SELECT>
<div class="twoDivs" id="colors"></div>
<div class="twoDivs" id="shapes"></div>
```

This should hold enough hints and tips to get you going... :)